# How to provide scanned barcodes for my android app

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am developing an android app and i need to provide it scanned barcodes saved as numbers from Barcode Scanner. What I have: button with onClick starts barcode scanner. It´s in a multiple scann mode or samething like than.I scann several BC´s. On resume i want to load those scanned EAN´s. But when i load it from sdcard/BarcodeScanner/History/someHistoryFile.csv It´s empty.
Anybody knows, where are barcodes saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV file is only created if the user chooses to save the History to a file. It is not created automatically. You could perhaps instruct your users to do this. Or you can request scans by Intent one after the other (not bulk mode) and record the results in your app.